# Dataset samples two gaussian distributions with unknown frequencies. I know the mean/variance of one gaussian. How do I calculate the other?

Tags: python, math, statistics

I have some real world data that is made up of two sub-populations with unknown frequencies. I know the mean and variance of one of the two Gaussians exactly, but do not know the mean and variance of the second Gaussian.

What I would like to do is input into a model the known gaussian mean and variance, and have the model output the second gaussian mean/variance, and the weights/frequencies of the known and unknown gaussian distributions.

Does something like this exist already?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `GaussianMixture` class from `scikit-learn` has code for fitting Gaussian mixture models. Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0], [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
print(gm.means_)
print(gm.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]]))
```